# API Rest con Grails 2.5.6: ¿Como configurar URIs sin UrlMapping ? Como notation sobre el método

Tags: api, rest, grails, uri

Tengo una API Rest con Grail 2.5.6 y estoy implementando algunas mejoras y buenas prácticas.
En este caso necesito implementar la regla:

- *Usar kebab-case en URLs*
- *Mal uso: /systemOrders o /system_orders*
- *Uso Recomendado: /system-orders*

Sé que puedo configurar el archivo UrlMapping para cada método y lo soluciono. Pero entiendo que debería existir alguna notation sobre el método que me permita conigurar era URI.

En la documentación de grails 4.0 veo el siguiente ejemplo:

```
@Get("/search?limit=25&media=music&entity=album&term={term}")
SearchResult search(String term)
```

¿Para **Grail 2.5.6** existe alguna alternativa similar al **@Get**?

Answer (score 0):

Finalmente con prueba y error, dí con la solución. Les dejo el ejemplo de cómo estaba y cómo quedó el controller

Antes:

```
 class LoginController {
 static allowedMethods = [userInfo: 'GET']
   
   def userInfo() {}

}
```

Ahora:

```
 class LoginController {
 static allowedMethods = ['user-info': 'GET']
   
   def "user-info"() {} // <-- aquí está el cambio

}
```

Definiendo el nombre del método entre comillas pude implementar *kebab-case*